# Scraping Deeply Nested HTML Tags, Python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I know that there are similar questions, but none of the answers worked for me. I am trying to get the src link from the img tag with class "ui mini avatar image" as you can see in the image below:
[image: nested tags]

I did not want to go through 6 div tags to reach it, but both ways did not work. The search is returning NoneType. This is the code I am trying to use:

```
urls = df.iloc[:,-1].values  
for url in urls:
  soup = BeautifulSoup(url, 'lxml')
  a_tag = soup.find('a', class_ ='left')
  img = a_tag.find('img', class_= 'ui mini avatar image')
  link = img.get_attribute('src')
  print(link)
  break
```

Please note that I stored the links I needed in a csv file and I am using Pandas to read it.
Here is the first link if you need to check it out: https://www.zomato.com/review/kMZEvAx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use css selector with `select_one`:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

headers = {
    "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.93 Safari/537.36"
}


soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get("https://www.zomato.com/review/kMZEvAx", headers=headers).text)
print(soup.select_one(".ui.mini.avatar.image").get("src"))
```

Print:

```
'https://b.zmtcdn.com/images/placeholder_200.png'
```

---

- Why did your solution doesn't work?

Your method `find` would only return the first `<a>` tag which class is `left`.

Comment: I am starting to think my problem is reading the urls from the csv. Pandas did not work, so  I tried csv reader and I am trying to fix the issue.

Comment: @Jana.k Just debug to test your code, and don't forget to add headers for your request.